# jQuery: Get scrollTop when mouse is pressed

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousemove, scrolltop

I have a question:
How to get scrollTop() value when a mouse button is pressed?

I have designed an option that lets user to draw a rectangle but an area in which drawing is possible has scrollbar. I would like to increase height of the rectangle while mouse is on the edge of window (the area is scrolling then) but jQuery is not getting scrollTop value properly before the mouse button is released.

Scheme:
Mouse button is pressed -> div is created at pointer coordinates and:

> var sc1=$('#contentWrap').scrollTop();

Mouse is moved -> div size is changed and:

> var sc2=$(#contentWrap').scrollTop();
>   if (sc2>sc1) //it returns false

The problem is that unless the mouse button is released var sc2 will have the same value as sc1, even if #contentWrap is scrolled.

PS Excause me for any mistakes - I'm still learning English